# Matrix keyboard 4*4 arduino

Tags: c, matrix, arduino, keypad

I have a problem with keyboard connected into 4*4 matrix. I use only 14 push buttons. The problem is that all push buttons work on Arduino Mega. On Uno works only 3,4 - 5,6 - B,C. I don't understand why it doesn't work. Could someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Here is my code

```
    #include <Keypad.h>

const byte ROWS = 4;
const byte COLS = 4;

char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1' , '2' , '3' , '4'},
  {'5' , '6' , '7' , '8'},
  {'9' , 'A' , 'B' , 'C'},
  {'D' , 'E' , 'F' , 'G'}
  };


byte rowPins[ROWS] = {13,12,11,10};
byte colPins[COLS] = {0,1,2,3};

Keypad keypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  char key = keypad.getKey();
  if(key != NO_KEY){
    Serial.println(key);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your connections are correct? Pins 0 & 1 for example on UNO are configured for serial communication by default, if my memory serves me right, though one would suspect that the `Keypad` constructor would handle that.

Comment: Great, it was problem with 0,1 pins. They are for communication, but I didn't know I can't use it for buttons. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On an [Arduino UNO](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) pins *0* & *1* are configured for serial communication, if you use the [`Serial`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Serial) library. Try changing those pins to some of the other digital pins.

As pure speculation, trying to read from the pins with `digitalRead()` or such in this state will [yield a LOW](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=186107.0) and so the `Keypad` library will never consider the column active and so buttons that reside on those columns will never work.